# Build error after upgrade Azure SDK from 2.4 to 2.6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-roles

I just upgraded my web role project (and solution) from Azure SDK 2.4 to Azure SDK 2.6 using the upgrade functionality under project properties > application.

When I am building my application, everything works well but when I try to run it (and start up the Azure emulator and such) it gives the following error when I click "NO" if I want to proceeed with build errors:

> unable to get setting value Parameter name: profileName

See build output: [image: Build output]

Nothing more. When I open my output I can not find anything related to this. It looks like the build is done successfully.

If I click "YES" VS serves a popup with this message:

> Failed to debug the Microsoft Azure Cloud Service project. The output
>   directory "D:\path\to\folder\src\project\csx\O" does not exist.

Maybe it has something to do with the emulator?

Can some one help? Much appreciated!

Comment: That is the exact wording of the error message?

Comment: Yes. That's why it is marked as quote :)

Comment: that's quite the unusual use of English for an error message.   Can you show a screenshot of that?  Also, have you tried rebuilding your project?

Comment: Added a screenshot. Yes, I've tried rebuilding it, but the error only occurs when I run my application, not during build.

Comment: seems like a bug to me.  I would submit a bug report at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio

Comment: definitely shows 1 failed there though, so one of your projects isn't compiling;  Presumably it has a `profileNameError` property within it somewhere.

Comment: Yes, it says that but none of my projects are failing. I think that is my web role project (ccproj), not any of my csproj files.

Comment: one definitely ***is*** failing to compile.  You are getting an error asking if you want to continue after receiving a build error.  If you hit NO, then your build is aborted.  If you hit YES, then it still tries to run the program anyway, but it can't, because the project didn't build, hence it doesn't exist in the output directory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77637/discussion-between-ydd1987-and-claies).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We also encountered this issue.

It appears that even if the Service Configuration you've selected in the Run/Debug settings is say, Dev.Local - you need to have a service configuration called `ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg` or you'll encounter this precise error.

At any case, once we created a cscfg called `ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg` this problem ceased, even though we were not referencing it.

Comment: Interesting. About two weeks ago we upgraded from 2.4 to 2.6 and did not see this error on any of our Azure projects. We have six Azure projects in our solution, only one has a ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg, the other five only have ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg.

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Using 2.8 SDK, cleaned up my solution. Search in files does not bring up "Local" at all but still i need to have it.

Comment: OMG...We have to have `ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg`!

Answer (score 10):

It's something nasty about diagnostics which the 2.7 upgrade (in my case) attaches everywhere. Remove diagnostics from your roles (web.config, role definitions) and I bet you'll have some luck.

Update: we never got to the bottom of this. Unless you are happy without diagnostics, life really is simpler if you just give in and make sure you have a Foo.Local.cscfg!

Comment: Worked for me. For those wondering where the Diagnostics option is: right-click the role > Properties > Uncheck Enable Diagnostics.

Comment: For us the problem was that the diagnostic connection string wasn't specified where the 2.7 SDK expects it to be. Simply unchecking "Enable Diagnostics", saving, and re-checking "Enable Diagnostics" has rectified the problem and Diagnostics is working as well.

Comment: Cool. Do you have any record of what that actually reconfigured in xml?

Comment: Diagnostics option is problem here.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a catch-all error. I've just encountered it, and the root cause in my case appears to be that I had the `thumbprintAlgorithm` for a certificate incorrectly set. I found this out when I tried to *Package...* it and got a useful error message, so that's one thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have an XML syntax error in ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg