# Build Error on upgrading Azure SDK to 2.9.6 - Unable to get setting value Parameter name: profileName

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, azure-storage, azure-cloud-services

After upgrading the Azure SDK version to 2.9.6 from 2.5, while running the application getting error "Unable to get setting value Parameter name: profileName".

I have followed this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196556/build-error-after-upgrade-azure-sdk-from-2-4-to-2-6) and it does not resolve my issue.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: But if you run `Build` it builds ok?

Comment: Yes, it builds fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can repro it if there is no serviceConfiguration.Local.cscfg with azure sdk 2.9.6.

[image]

> I have followed this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196556/build-error-after-upgrade-azure-sdk-from-2-4-to-2-6) and it does not resolve my issue.

If it is not existing or correct `serviceConfiguration.Local.cscfg`.  I resolved the issue by copy the `serviceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg` and rename the copy file to the `serviceConfiguration.Local.cscfg`.  The following is my detail steps, hope it is useful.

If the solution has [work role] and  [web role], please have a try to make sure both of the projects have  corresponding `serviceConfiguration.Local.cscfg` file.

1. Right click the Cloud Service and select the [Manage configurations..] option.

[image]

2. We can  remove ,copy and rename the configuration file with popup windows

[image]

3. After that it works correctly

[image]